# Using String Array item per item

Tags: java, arrays

I need to use a String Array to make a list of frequency used in a classrom,

Example:

```
String names[] = new String [50];
```

Then i need to call position after position to be inserted a name.

Example:

```
String names[0], then names[1], names[2] ...  names[50],
```

Each one with a diferent name and inserted using a **JOptionPane.showInputDialog**...

If possible I want to continue the insertion in the array from the next position that I stopped

Example:

```
inserted  names[0],[1],[2] then stop... now again inserting names[3],[4] and going on...
```

Here is what i have now...

```
// reserved to use in menu loop

int option1=0;
int option2=0;

// array that will keep all the classrom students names

String names[] = new String [50];

//in need to find a way to fill position after position of the array with names

names[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please, insert student name"); 

// in need to find a way to call next position in awway

names[1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please, insert student name");
```

Comment: Keep track of position using a counter.. that will solve your probelm..

Comment: how can i use a position in a String array to receive a JOptionPane.showInputDialog ?

Comment: I suggest to use `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String[]`. It has `add(...)` method for appending more items at the end of the list.

Comment: thinksteep im starting to write the code right now, nothing done yet...

Comment: Petr can you show to me a example using this ArrayList please?

Answer (score 1):

You would want a loop. If you want to be able to save state and continue later, I would use a while-loop and a private field to keep the current index, or simply use a ArrayList as previously suggested:

```
boolean keepGoing = true;
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
while (keepGoing) {
    string newName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter student name: ");
    if (newName == null) { //User has pressed "Cancel" or left the textbox empty
        keepGoing = false;
    } else {
        names.add(newName);
    }
}
```

An ArrayList lets you add elements without specifying an index, and thus saves you from the trouble of keeping an index.
As this actually *is* your homework, I will leave it as an exercise to the reader (always wanted to write that) to figure out how to do it with a regular array

Answer (score 0):

you might need a for(String current = new String() : names) { insert into the optionPane }

is this your homework or something... ?

Comment: Yes it is, i'm new in Java and this is a homework, so, i need to insert this line where exactly ?

Comment: well stackoverflow is not the site where you get homework done. you present what have YOU done by now and we correct it or help you complete. What's your code snippet ?

Comment: i need to find a way to field a position in the array with a JOptionPane.showInputDialog i will show what is done... 1 moment please

Comment: Code added to main question, please have a look